# Laravel app.js and bootstrap.js are not included?

Tags: jquery, node.js, laravel, laravel-5

I installed a fresh Laravel 5.8 and included the

```
<script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>
```

at the bottom of `welcome.blade.php`. To avoid error,  set a div with `id=app`.

If I write `alert(123)` inside `public/js/app.js` it will be alerted when I visit this page and it is ok. I noticed that in line `60329` of `public/js/app.js` it has

> **webpack_require**(/*! C:\xampp\htdocs\br1\resources\js\app.js */"./resources/js/app.js");

sounds it includes the `resources\js\app.js` and `resources\js\app.js` includes `resources\js\bootstrap.js`

When I write the `alert(22)` in  `resources\js\app.js` or `resources\js\bootstrap.js` nothing will be alerted while it must alert something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `public/js/app.js` file is a file built from the resources in `resources/js/app.js`. If you want to modify the javascript, you should update the `resources/js/app.js` and compile these resources using `npm run dev` in your terminal.

More information about compiling resources can be found in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/mix

Answer (score 1):

Your laravel application is loading javascript from public/app.js. That is why when you add the alert directly in public/app.js the alert shows up just as you would expect. To update this file after making changes to resources/js/app.js you would have to run the npm run dev command from the terminal. This will compile the code in resources/js/app.js and consequently update public/app.js